# Call to httpclient throws a 404 response when using OWIN SelfHost

Tags: c#, owin, webapi2

I have the following call to a selfhosted OWIN API:

```
const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";
using (WebApp.Start<ApiSelfHost>(url: baseAddress))
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/v1/orders/test/status").Result;
}
```

Which is based on (*I got that working*):

[Use OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)

The response returns the following:

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

But if I run the actual API and go to:

```
http://localhost:51823/api/v1/orders/test/status
```

I get a valid response.

That controller action has this signature:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/orders/{orderReference}/status")]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrderStatus([FromUri]string orderReference)
```

I tried changing that port `9000` to `51823`, just to be sure, but that doesn't matter.

I have the following OWIN packages installed:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Testing" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
```

**Question**

> Any pointers to why the url cannot be found (throws 404)?

Comment: please share the code of `ApiSelfHost`

Comment: @user1859022: I found the solution in the meantime, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A few hours later I got it working! As was to be expected it was something deeper:

My controller gave this error:

```
no parameterless constructor defined for this object
```

Despite having set up IoC type registrations:

```
source.Register(c => MyDbContextMock.Create())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

I was however missing this line:

```
source.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(OrderController).Assembly);
```

---

Full startup set up with injection:

```
public class ApiSelfHost : Startup
{
    public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

        var container = httpConfiguration.ConfigureAutofac();

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfiguration);

        app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Where `ConfigureAutofac` is an extension on `HttpConfiguration`:

```
internal static IContainer ConfigureAutofac(this HttpConfiguration source)
{
    var container = new ContainerBuilder()
        .ConfigureAutofac()
        .Build();

    source.ConfigureDependencyInjection(container);

    return container;
}
```

And one on `ContainerBuilder` as well:

```
internal static ContainerBuilder ConfigureAutofac(this ContainerBuilder source)
{
    source.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(OrderController).Assembly);

    source.Register(c => MyDbContextMock.Create())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest();

    return source;
}
```

`Startup` base class is the actual one from the API.